# Angular2 not handling touch events on a tablet

Tags: javascript, angular, touch, mouseevent

I have an Angular2 app with a button.
I want to execute a function every 200ms while the button is pressed down, and stop the interval when the button is released.
This is the code I wrote:

```
<button mat-fab color="primary" (mousedown)="onMouseDown()" (mouseup)="onMouseUp()">Click Me</button>
```

and

```
onMouseDown() {
   this.mInterval = setInterval(...,200);
}
onMouseUp() {
   clearInterval(this.mInterval);
}
```

This works perfectly on a PC, but when I test it on my **Android** tablet, the onMouseDown function is called only when I **click** the button (long press / holding the button down doesn't trigger it at all).

I tried using **(touchstart)** and **(touchend)** directives (because in the JQuery app I have they work perfectly on this tablet) - but they never gets called...

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I tried using HammerJS but (pressup) isn't triggered when I release the button.